# How to run a MYSQL query on a pre-defined fixed time?

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql insert query.  I need to run the query everyday, at 11:00 AM.

How do I execute a query on a fixed time in MySQL?
In MS-SQL i can easily do it by SQL Server agent job scheduler.  So, is there any way to run a predefined schedule query in My-SQL?  My MySQL version is: 5.5.12.

Comment: Thanks to all.Let check by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) to achieve the above purpose in Mysql.

To create an event, you can use the create event statement. [Here is an explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) with example.

Something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT e_totals
->     ON SCHEDULE AT '2006-02-10 23:59:00'
->     DO INSERT INTO test.totals VALUES (NOW());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mysql 5.1.6 + use the event scheduler
see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

or how about setting up a job in your OS using cron or at ?