# Blank rows are inserting in the database table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a project that is developed in CakePHP with MySQL. The problem is daily 2-3 records are getting entered in the 'products' table with 0 values in the fields.

There are 2 ways of entering data via application - Front-end & Admin panel. Both forms are authenticated (via ACL) and having validations (client side and server side). But not able to find how these blank records are coming on daily basis.

Any help regarding, in which area I have to look to solve the issue, would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code of those 2 places... there is not enough info I think to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How come people say **rows are inserting in the database automatically**?.

A **computer** doesn't do any thing by its **own unless** you **direct** it to do.

**Current Question** where it stands*

I see two **possibilities**:

1.There might be an **[event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)** running at a fixed time in your **DB**. **[Explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)**

**[Referenced from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597850/how-to-run-a-mysql-query-on-a-pre-defined-fixed-time/6597896#6597896)**

2.Someone might be doing it without your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is no scheduler in the DB, either anyone has created it, even records are getting entered at different timestamp. Yes I am going to change the DB password, so that if anyone is doing this without my knowledge could be caught.