# How to scheduled MYSQL query on a defined fixed time?

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a my  mysql table where  i want to run mysql query daily at scheduled time

my query is

```
truncate  dashboard
```

I need to run the query everyday, at 6:00 PM.

How can i achieve this

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597850/how-to-run-a-mysql-query-on-a-pre-defined-fixed-time)

Comment: Use Event Scheduler dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a schedule:

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2014-09-13 18:00:00'
      ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO BEGIN
    TRUNCATE dashboard;
  END
```